# Как передать float в функцию которая принимает UnsafeMutableRawPointer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Я создаю коннект IOS c s7-300 контроллером. коннект есть но не могу корректно передать значение типа `Float`,
 У меня возникает вопрос с `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`! как туда записать `float` Значение.

Код:    `Cli_DBWrite(Client:S7Object,DBNumber:Int32,Size:Int32,pUsrData:*UnsafeMutableRawPointer)`

`Cli_DBWrite(Client,1000,4,4,????)` как сюда записать значение `Float` подскажите пожалуйста `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`

Comment: а Int не устроит?

Comment: нет побывал. Надо записать значение в UnsafeMutableRawPointer

Comment: в смысле int сконвертировать в UnsafeMutableRawPointer вместо float

Comment: а как это сделать можно код?

Comment: `UnsafeMutableRawPointer(bitPattern: myInt)!`

Comment: вся строка будет выглядеть так `Cli_DBWrite(Client,1000,4,4,UnsafeMutableRawPointer(bitPattern: myInt)!)`

Comment: let int: l=10 
UnsafeMutablerawpointer(bitPattern: I)
Вот так?

Comment: let int: l=10  let unsafePointer = UnsafeMutablerawpointer(bitPattern: I). ага типа такого

Comment: А как обратно с UnsafeMutabeRawPointer  В Int?

Comment: bitPattern не подходит Макс

Comment: при помощи mutating передает данные но криво помогите плиз как при помощи UnsafeMutalabeRawPointer передать Float

Answer (score 0):

В `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` значение Float можно записать таким образом в Swift версии 4.

```
func __test_so_578002() {
    print("[TEST]: \(#function)")

    let x0 = Float(123456.7890)
    let ptr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride, alignedTo: 1)
    ptr.storeBytes(of: x0, as: Float.self)

    // Используйте ptr по назначению...

    let x1 = ptr.load(as: Float.self)
    print((x0, x1))

    print("[/TEST]")
}
```

На выходе проверка:

```
[TEST]: __test_so_578002()
(123456.789, 123456.789)
[/TEST]
```

Answer (score 0):

Не проверял в Swift 4, но есть довольно компактный вариант в Swift 3

```
var testVar:Float = 15.0
let testPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&testVar)
let newValue = testPointer.load(as: Float.self) // newValue = testVar
```

Вам нужно передать в метод testPointer

Но Apple, вот [тут](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html), пишет что можно еще проще. Пусть у Вас есть некий метод принимающий `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`

```
func takesAMutablePointer(_ p: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>) {
// ...
}


var x: Float = 0.0
var a: [Float] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
takesAMutablePointer(&x)
takesAMutablePointer(&a)
```

так что в Вашем случае просто

```
var yourFloatValue: = 3.141592
Cli_DBWrite(Client, 1000, 4, 4, &yourFloatValue)
```